# Is it possible to add time with date in DateEntry?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkcalendar

I'm using the following code for date. I need to add time with date. How can I do this?

```
ent_date_time = DateEntry(self.frame2, locale='en_US', date_pattern='y-mm-dd)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've seen, it is not possible to get the current time using Tkinter's DateEntry.

However you can use, the `datetime.now()` function to get the current date and time. Observe:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> print(datetime.now())
2020-12-22 22:51:26.223754
```